# Class of Sendinblue could not found in Repository in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sendinblue

I am using Sendinblue for sending email via API in paravel. The problem is when I use Repository for managing sending email, Laravel could not find Sendinblue API. Itest different packages for using Sendinblue for Laravel, but still have problem for using it. This is aa error when I used juanparati/sendinblue Package for sending Email.

[image]

Comment: try write it \SendinBlue\Client\Configuration with "\" in the first

Comment: Did you register  the service provider into the `"config/app.php":

    Juanparati\Sendinblue\ServiceProvider::class,`

Comment: yes I registered. I did exact instruction of package